# Refresh page when it passes width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a website and I need to refresh page when it passes width of 1024 pixels. It's possible?
I need this because can width < 1024 px, I load another script.

Comment: Use CSS Media Queries to alter content and layout when size changes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(window).width < 1024){ 
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to refresh content not just change styling. If that is the case you will want to use `window.matchMedia()`.

Here's how you use it:

`var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );`

The matches property returns true or false depending on the query result, e.g.

```
if (mq.matches) {
  // window width is at least 500px
} else {
  // window width is less than 500px
}
```

This snippet was [taken from here](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/).

Comment: Support for this is spotty and pure CSS Media Queries can control content loading.

Comment: Actually, support is not bad (e.g. IE10 and up) and all other modern browsers have full support. IMHO, content loading should be done by JavaScript not CSS.